# jQuery .attr doesn't attribute width or height

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, jquery-attributes

The following code attributes the src to `.ajax-loader` which is an `img` but not the height or width. Am I doing something wrong?

```
  $(".ajax-loader").attr({
    src: "http://test.com/loading.gif",
    height: 16,
    width: 16
  });
```

Edit: This is being loaded by Contact Form 7 which is a WordPress plugin. I don't understand because the src is changing fine. However, one thing I noticed was that the height and width attributes aren't present. I am trying to add them in. Is this why they aren't showing up?

[Link to website](http://keebs.com)

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NH7T8/. How do you know it's not setting the width and height?

Comment: @Blender This is being loaded by Contact Form 7 which is a WordPress plugin. I don't understand because the `src` is changing fine. However, one thing I noticed was that the `height` and `width` attributes aren't present. I am trying to add them in. Is this why they aren't showing up?

Comment: @Desi: Something else is interfering with it. Do the attributes show up at all?

Comment: @Blender No, they don't.

Comment: @Desi: Well, there's not much that can be done if we can't see the actual code or at least the website.

Comment: @Blender I added the link to the website in the post. If you click on the orange button at the top right, the contact form slides down, and from there you can click 'send' and see the ajax loading gif pop up.

Comment: I went to your site, typed the code in the console, and it worked. only thing is I had to add  `.css("visibility", "visible");` to see it

Comment: @user2264587 Strange. I just tested it in the console and it did indeed work. However, I put it in the code in my JS file and emptied the cache, and it's still not showing up. Could it just be a matter of time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.css()`:

```
$(".ajax-loader").attr("
    "src", "http://keebs.com/wp-content/themes/keebs/images/ajax-loader.gif")
   .css({
    height: "16px",
    width: "16px"
  });
```

Comment: in `.css()` you should use **px** like `height: 16px` , and it's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the CSS height and width properties: `$(".ajax-loader").css({height:"16px", width:"16px"});`

Answer (score 0):

Use .height() and .width() to set the width and height.

```
$(".ajax-loader").width(16).height(16);
```